# Exception handling in python3

Tags: python, exception

I was doing one hackerrank challenge via my company website. The question is a simple ValueError raise exception based on the condition - Given two integers a and b - if a > 150 or b < 100 then raise exception . Second condition is if sum of the two integers is greater than 400 , then also raise the ValueError exception. If no condition satisfies then print "All values in range". I have written below code and it passed 7 out of 9 test case. Now I am not able to figure where could be my code is failing for those two test cases. It outputs - All values in range - message in the failed test cases. Can someone point what more I can add to the code to pass the remaining two test cases.

```
def handle_excl():
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    sums = a + b
    
    
    if (a > 150) or (b < 100):
        raise ValueError('Input integers value out of range.')
    elif sums > 400:
        raise ValueError('Their sum is out of range')
    else:
        print('All in range.')
```

Above is the main code and please help how can I resolve the two failed test cases?

Comment: your code fits the criteria you specified, so it is probably something else you missed from the task.

Comment: Have you checked that it is not strict inequalities? `>=` for example

Comment: temporarily:  `print('All in range.',a,b,sums)` - then inspect the output and compare the values against your task

Comment: @ChrisOram I tried >= but still the cases are failed. This problem is really checking my patience :)

Comment: Maybe they meant printing all ints between `a` and `b`? `for i in range(a, b): print(i)`

Comment: The failed test case says - "All in range". It means the output should have been either "values out of range" or "sum out of range". Now the hidden test case had two integers that somehow skipped the first two if condition and straight jumped to the last else condition. If the two integers were both negative or either one was negative and other was positive. I mean which two integers can fail the case or can the code be modified to  accept that corner case?

Comment: Maybe they specified the conditions for `absolute values` in the task!?

Comment: Without knowing what the values of *a* and *b* are when the test fails, it's impossible to say what's going on. Also, do you realise that the *else* and *elif* conditions are unnecessary in this case?

Comment: @BrutusForcus - elif condition is unnecessary and I think we can use just a separate if statement. But how to put else statement without using else ?

Comment: @isilia see answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is in response to a comment I made about the fact that elif and else conditions are unnecessary in this case:

```
def checkvals(a, b):
  if (a > 150) or (b < 100):
    raise ValueError('Input integers value out of range')
  if a + b > 400:
    raise ValueError('Sum out of range')
  print('All in range')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, you just have to remove the fullstop(.) sign in this line-> print("All in range.")

```
def handle_excl():
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    sums = a + b

    if (a > 150) or (b < 100):
        raise ValueError('Input integers value out of range.')
    elif sums > 400:
        raise ValueError('Their sum is out of range')
    else:
        print('All in range')
```